# Can't manage an instance of Cursor for my SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I've successfully copied an existing SQLite database to android, as it was recommended here http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/
and now when i'm writing

> Cursor cur = db.db.query("student", 
>                   null, null, null, null, null, null);

The app breaks trying to create a cursor. I'm sure there is a "student" table.
Could you help me with suggesting any reasons of why this happens, please?

Comment: I've never tried, but is it legal to have a query "null"? I mean, I thought you had to have something like "SELECT * FROM table"..?

Answer (score 0):

I just guessing, but `db.db.query()` looks wrong... you sure you didn't mean `db.query()` ?

Comment: db.db is OK) first db - is my dbHelper class and the second one is actually a DataBase instance.

Answer (score 0):

A more collaborative answer than my comment. I would think you'll be fine by doing something like this tutorial does http://droidreign.com/2010/10/dev-tutorials-android-sqlite-database-basics/ . About half the way down is the part you are looking for.

Edit: I guess the problem with your query is that you ask for **none** of the columns (second parameter in your query). It should probably be at least one of your columns.

Comment: By the way, you can also do a `rawQuery` something like this: `db.db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM student", null);`